# Getting error when adding "contact" through web service API

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to add "Contacts" through web service but kept getting error as follows:

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

If I commented out that line as follows:

```
//cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = CR302000.ContactSummary.ContactID });
```

I got no error any more but there is no contact added.

The code is below:

```
            CR302000Content CR302000 = context.CR302000GetSchema();
            context.CR302000Clear();

            List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();               

            //add header info

            //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = CR302000.ContactSummary.ContactID });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = contact.LastName, LinkedCommand = CR302000.DetailsSummary.LastName });

            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "CA", LinkedCommand = CR302000.DetailsAddress.Country });


            cmds.Add(CR302000.Actions.Save);

            CR302000Content[] CR302000content = context.CR302000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
```

Can anybody help me to let me know what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have missed something - my code works now for some reason. I still use the same code as I posted here with that line involving "Contact ID" commented out and "Actions.Save", but it worked somehow. Not sure why but I'm closing this question now. Thanks to guys who have responded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what you see in the screen is actually the display name not the true contact ID it is a special field Acumatica does this in a lot of places and I just work around it.

You should try and use the  tag in the display name and that might do it. (I guessed at the tags reference your Webservice for the proper name on DisplayName)

```
cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = CR302000.ContactSummary.DisplayName });
```

Or you could pull the last ContactID assigned and increment that number (+1) and use that as your value for CR302000.ContactSummary.ContactID which should save the record as well.

Answer (score 0):

There should be command(Action) Insert and i suppose you can use

CR302000.Actions.Insert instead of using key

Comment: I tried using "insert" instead of "save" but no luck.